# Facebook PHP SDK over https

Tags: php, facebook

Im trying to use the facebook login from https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk

It works fine over HTTP but fails to login over HTTPS, The app page lists the login page as https://my.url.com

Both pages have a get redirect with code and state, which are the same length for the working and non working URL.

I would prefer to use https for all login pages.

By Doesnt work I mean after a successful login the token is appid|appsecret and the user returns ID of 0 instead of the actual user id which has just completed the login

Comment: Do you check Server's configuration? May be "nginx" doing some things with GET params via https? And you must known that sending request to https from http is forbidden by CORS policy, check this thing too.

Comment: Im using apache, CORS wont apply because javascript isnt involved. The process is either all HTTPS or all HTTP there is no mixing. All HTTP works fine, all HTTPS doesnt work

Comment: How are you initializing the Facebook PHP SDK? Post some PHP code.

Comment: the standard example https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue to be the Redirect URL. Code was being used from http://webcheatsheet.com/php/get_current_page_url.php

which puts the port :443 on the url. During the redirect the facebook info gets "lost"

Changing their code to allow for this fixes the problem. though with or without the :443 its still a valid URL and should really work

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using the [HybridAuth](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/) library? I've always had it dump me into https on Facebook

Answer (score 1):

The `:443` is what tells the browser to connect over HTTPS,  the default port for HTTP is 80 and 443 for HTTPS.

Perhaps the issue is something to do with Facebook having cached your domain as port 80

You can clear facebook's cache of your site, and troubleshoot other URL related problems with their official URL debugger https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/